# Delay between number of requests

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm using simplexml to load data from another provider via a while loop. To avoid being blocked by a firewall or flooding their server, I'd like to add a small delay via sleep after 500 requests. This is my existing code...

```
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

    // Load the XML
    $url = "http://www.domain.com/models.asp?txtYear=" . $line_of_text[0] . "&txtMake=" . $line_of_text[1];
    $xmlinfo = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $i = 0;
    $value = (string) $xmlinfo->table[$i]->txtmodel;

    while ($value != '') {
        $value = (string) $xmlinfo->table[$i]->txtmodel;
        if ($value != '') {
            fputcsv($handle, array(
                $line_of_text[0],
                $line_of_text[1],
                $value
            )); 
        } else {
            // Do nothing
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

I'm hoping this is easy to do -- I look forward to the assistance! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count every instance of the loop and if it reached 500, put it into sleep and restart it:

```
$meter = 0;
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    // Load the XML
    $url = "http://www.domain.com/models.asp?txtYear=" . $line_of_text[0] . "&txtMake=" . $line_of_text[1];
    $xmlinfo = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $i = 0;
    $value = (string) $xmlinfo->table[$i]->txtmodel;

    while ($value != '') {
        $value = (string) $xmlinfo->table[$i]->txtmodel;
        if ($value != '') {
            fputcsv($handle, array(
                $line_of_text[0],
                $line_of_text[1],
                $value
            )); 
        } else {
            // Do nothing
        }
        $i++;
    }
    //Increase the meter by 1
    $meter++;
    //Check if the limit is reached and if yes, sleep for 60 seconds
    if($meter == 500){
    sleep(60);
    $meter = 0;
    }
}
```